# Defining composition of multiples of functions.

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

There's this following theorem in my book whose proof is left as an exercise.

**Theorem:** Let $V(F)$ be a vector space and let $U_1,U_2\in\mathcal{L}(V)$. Then, $\forall a\in F, a(U_1U_2)=(aU_1)U_2=U_1(aU_2)$.

Here, $\mathcal{L}(V)$ denotes the vector space of all linear transformations from $V$ to $V$ and $AB$ (also denoted by $A\circ B)$ denotes the composition of two linear transformations $A$ and $B$.

Now, I know that there is a bijection between matrices and linear transformations and as such, I can view the theorem in an alternative way where the theorem is simply equivalent to the product of two matrices $U_1,U_2$ and scalar $a$, which makes the theorem look trivial.

But, I'm having a bit of a problem proving this while considering $U_1,U_2$ as linear transformations.

I have established equality between LHS and MHS but I can't establish the equality with the RHS.

---

This made me ponder over something related to this that might point out the error in my thinking.

Consider functions $f,g\colon A\mapsto A$ and consider real scalars $a,b$. Then, how exactly do we define $(af\circ bg)(x)$ ?

Do we define it as $a\cdot f(b\cdot g(x))$ or do we define it any other way?

I've been using the above definition in my work. Maybe if this definition is incorrect, that might be the reason for my error? Can you guys help me out? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I would read $af\circ bg$ as $(af)\circ (bg)$ where $af$ is the map $x\mapsto xf(x)$ and similarly for $bg$. Thus $af\circ bg$ would be the map $x\mapsto af(bg(x))$ as you suggested. But due the all associativity around, I can't imagine this level of detail would matter.

Comment: For the example you have, we can't even define $af(x)$. You need some structure on $A$ to be able to define product with a real in any reasonable way. If $A$ is $\mathbb{R}$ then it's easy and you can just define it as $af(x)=a(f(x))$ where you have multiplication on the right side since $f(x)\in\mathbb{R}$. Obviously you don't need to have $\mathbb{R}$ it's enough to have any structure for which you know how to multiply by elements of $\mathbb{R}$ on the range side of $f,g$.

Comment: @DRF Presumably $a,b\in F$ and $F$ is a field.

Comment: @GitGud you could presume that. In which case you first of all go smack against what the OP writes "and consider real scalars $a$,$b$" and also you aren't helping yourself much since there is no relationship between $A$ and $F$. My point wasn't really to nitpick though. I was more trying to say that how $af$ is defined depends quite a bit on what structures you are dealing with. If $A$ is a vector space over $F$ then $af$ is usually $a\cdot(f(x))$ and it is sensible to interpret$(af\circ bg)$  as $(af)\circ(bg)$ which turns out to be $a(f(b(g)))$ (you don't really even need the dots).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $U_1$ is a linear transformation then for $a \in F$, it's true for any $v \in V$ that $aU_1(v) = U_1(av)$. In particular it's true for $v = U_2(x), x \in V$. That is,
$$aU_1(U_2(x)) = U_1(aU_2(x))$$

for all $x \in V$. That's the remaining piece of the puzzle.

It's also possible to prove this without explicitly using elements of $V$. The vector space axioms, and the fact that field multiplication is commutative, show that for any $a \in F$,

- the function $T_a \colon x \mapsto ax \colon  V \to V$ is a linear transformation, such that
- if $U$ is any linear transformation of $V$, then $T_a \circ U = U \circ T_a$.

(You have to use elements of $V$ to show *that*.) Using the fact that composition of functions is associative, and the fact that $aU = T_a \circ U$, the result now follows easily:
$$
\begin{align}
a (U_1 U_2) &= T_a \circ (U_1 \circ U_2) \\
&= (T_a \circ U_1) \circ U_2 \\
&= (U_1 \circ T_a) \circ U_2 \\
&= U_1 \circ (T_a \circ U_2) \\
&= U_1 (a U_2) \\
\end{align}
$$
Usually you'd just write $a$ for the linear transformation $x \mapsto ax$, by a slight "abuse of notation", but more explicit/pedantic notation can be clearer when you're first learning.

Comment: THANK YOU! I just checked it myself. I now realize how stupid this question was, haha.

Comment: Learn somethin' new every day ;)

Comment: I'm going to add another bit, about how to prove it without using elements of $V$.